# An example where a variable of type "Error" is declared & used

Tags: vba, excel

I would like to make a test where a variable of type `Error` is declared, and used later in a VBA program. I have written `=1/0` in cell `(5,6)` of the active sheet, therefore it has value `#DIV/0!`, then I try to run the following code:

```
Sub try()
   Dim x As Error
   y = ActiveSheet.Cells(5, 6).Value
   MsgBox TypeName(y)
   x = ActiveSheet.Cells(5, 6).Value
End Sub
```

The `MsgBox` does print `Error` for `y`, however, an error is raised in the line of the assignment to `x`: `Run-time error "91": Object variable or With block variable not set`.

Could anyone tell me what is wrong here, or gives me another example where a variable or type `Error` is declared & used?

Comment: It seems to me that `ActiveSheet.Cells(5, 6)` is `null`.

Comment: What are you wanting to do with checking if it is an error or not? Using `dim x as Error` won't let you check whether the cell has any error. Moreover, you are missing `option explicit` (i.e. you are using y without declaring it).

Comment: I do not want to check anything is an error or not. I just want to know in which case a `Dim x as Error` is used...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

an error in a cell is an error value, not an Error object

to use an error object:

```
   Dim x As Error
   Dim n As Long
   ActiveCell.Formula = "=1/0"
   For n = xlEvaluateToError To xlInconsistentListFormula
      Set x = ActiveCell.Errors(n)
      If x.Value Then MsgBox "Error in cell"
   Next n
```

Comment: OK... So do you have a code example of using Error object, or declaring an error value?

Comment: you can't declare an error value as a specific type-you must use Variant. I will update the answer to show an error object

Comment: Nice example. You might also refer the link to [Excel `Error` object](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa174214%28v=office.11%29.aspx) documentation.

Answer (score 0):

To retrieve the error message from the cell:

```
Sub try()
    Dim x As String
    Dim y As Variant
    y = ActiveSheet.Cells(5, 6).Value
    MsgBox TypeName(y)
    If TypeName(y) = "Error" Then
        x = ActiveSheet.Cells(5, 6).Text
        MsgBox x
    End If
End Sub
```

You would use Error as a function to retrieve the error message if all you had was the error number.